# Recursive reference to a list within itself

Tags: python, list, self-reference, repr

So I came across something very weird in python. I tried adding a reference to the list to itself. The code might help demonstrate what I am saying better than I can express. I am using IDLE editor(interactive mode).

```
>>>l=[1,2,3]
>>>l.append(l)
>>>print(l)
[1,2,3,[...]]
>>>del l[:-1]
>>>print(l)
[[...]]
```

So far the output is as expected. But when I do this.

```
y=l[:]
print(y)
```

To me it seems that the output should be

```
[[...]]
```

But it is

```
[[[...]]]
```

Apparently instead of creating a copy of the list, it puts a reference to the list in y.

**y[0] is l** returns True. I can't seem to find a good explanation for this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is only in the way the list is displayed. I.e. the value of `y` is exactly what you'd expect.

The difference in the way the lists are displayed results from the fact that, unlike `l`, `y` is not a self-referencing list:

```
l[0] is l
=> True
y[0] is y
=> False
```

`y` is not self-referencing, because `y` does not reference `y`. It references `l`, which is self-referencing.

Therefor, the logic which translates the list to a string detects the potential infinite-recursion one level deeper when working on `y`, than on `l`.

Answer (score 3):

This is perfectly expected. When Python prints recursive lists, it checks that the list it is printing hasn't yet been encountered and if it has prints `[...]`. An important point to understand is that it doesn't test for **equality** (as in `==`) but for **identity** (as in `is`). Therefore,

- when you print `l = [l]`. You have `l[0] is l` returns `True` and therefore it prints `[[...]]`.
- now `y = l[:]` makes a copy of `l` and therefore `y is l` returns `False`. So here is what happens. It starts printing `y` so it prints [ ??? ] where `???` is replaced by the printing of `y[0]`. Now `y[0]` is `l` and is not `y`. So it prints `[[???]]` with `???` replaced by `y[0][0]`. Now `y[0][0]` is `l` which has already been encountered. So it prints `[...]` for it giving finally `[[[...]]]`.

Comment: Could you elaborate? You lost me at **" It starts printing y : [ ??? ].....**

Comment: Also what if I actually wanted a copy of the list? I know I can just do the same with y in this case, but for the sake of discussion is there a way I can do it?

Comment: @Sabyasachi: It is clearer that way ?

Comment: @Sabyasachi: This second question is very ambiguous. Which list are you talking about ? I think you should think about the difference between deep copy and shallow copy (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)

Comment: Yes thanks it's clearer. I was talking about list l. Anyway I got it now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a *full copy* of the objects.  You need to use [`copy.deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) and you would see the expected results.

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> l=[1,2,3]
>>> l.append(l)
>>> print(l)
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
>>> del l[:-1]
>>> print(l)
[[...]]
>>> y=deepcopy(l)
>>> print(y)
[[...]]
>>> y[0] is l
False
>>>
```

When you use the slice notation to copy the list, the inner references are retained which cause the behavior that you observe.

Answer (score 1):

Slicing generates list of items. There is only one item - list "l". So, we have new list of one element - list "l".