# Python 2.7 - x.append(x) infinetly appends x?

Tags: python-2.7

I discovered a humorous situation when playing around in Python 2.7. It seems that when I append a list onto itself, it seems to infinitely append itself onto the list. Here is the example that I used:

```
>>> x = ['a','b','c']
>>> x.append(x)
>>> x
['a', 'b', 'c', [...]]
>>> x[3]
['a', 'b', 'c', [...]]
>>> x[3][3][3]
['a', 'b', 'c', [...]]
>>> x[3][2]
'c'
```

Why wouldn't it just output as:

```
>>> x = ['a','b','c']
>>> x.append(x)
>>> x
['a', 'b', 'c', ['a','b','c']]
```

I'm just curious as to why this happens. I can't seem to find anything that adequately explains why this is. Thank you all very much!

Comment: woh nice trick infinite dimension

Comment: See this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21798483/4996248 (this is the question which seems more like a duplicate of the current one, but this question itself was closed as a duplicate of the one I cited above)